# Swagger UI not working in Magento2: json schema not found

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento-2.1

I'm trying to view the cool interactive Swagger UI on my own running Magento 2.1 instance.

When I go to https://example.com/swagger it shows the swagger header, but under it is an error message:

```
Can't read swagger JSON from https://example.com/index.php/rest/default/schema?services=all
```

When I query that URI myself with

```
curl -X GET "https://example.com/rest/default/schema" -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken"
```

I get a 404 response with message `{"message":"Request does not match any route","trace":null}`

Do I need to do anything to generate the swagger json? Where is the controller that's supposed to process this request so that I can debug it? Why is this not working? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try by clearing your browser cache or some other browser or CTRL+R.

Comment: It's not a browser issue. That curl command is not running in the browser but on the terminal.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Me not yet, but someone just posted an answer, I have yet to try it.

Answer (score 7):

https://example.com/rest/default/schema is not available because you probably don't have a storeview with code "default".

So you have to create a storeview with code "default" 
OR 
you can edit(override of course) the template in the Magento Swagger module "view/frontend/templates:swagger-ui/index.phtml":

```
$schemaUrl = rtrim($block->getBaseUrl(), '/') . '/rest/default/schema?services=all';
```

and change it to:

```
 $schemaUrl = rtrim($block->getBaseUrl(), '/') . '/rest/[storecode]/schema?services=all';
```

Of course it would be better if Magento would make the storecode a parameter you can pass to the request.